# Netbook as server?

Tags: laptop

I'm thinking about this as a substitute for cheap little embedded systems like soekrises, used for lightweight server tasks.

The major advantages that I see over current tiny systems:

- built in monitor + keyboard
- built-in ups
- more commoditization

You also get the low power, low noise, smallness, etc advantages.  You lose the potential for multiple ethernet connections, but that's fine if you're not routing/firewalling or can use vlans or usb adapters.  I expect speed and reliability will improve over the next few years as flash drives continue to improve and get cheaper.

Is this a good/bad idea?  Has anyone else done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of a Soekris or similar solution is that it is purpose-built. The hardware is usually very stable and oriented at its exact role. Your netbook could not perform any of the tasks for which Soekrises are generally intended:

- Router
- Firewall
- Bridge
- Wifi AP
- PBX Server
- Light-use file server

The first three are not options because you only have a single NIC. The last three because you have no PCI expansion capabilities (for AP-capable wifi card, PRI/phone line termination, and RAID card, respectively). USB ethernet/wifi adapters are simply not feasible replacements for built-in capabilities.

A built-in monitor/keyboard is really not much of an advantage. Most embedded systems pump console ouptut out their serial port - you don't want to have to worry about a screen/keyboard/trackpad/etc in your rack or under the stack of hardware.

The built-in UPS is an interesting idea, but not compelling enough to overcome the other glaring deficiencies in a netbook.

Netbooks and laptops are best used for their original intent - portable end-user computing. Possibly there are a few minor niches where this might be useful (hobbyists who just need something running a particular OS permanently connected to their network), but I can't think of any within the scope of this forum (IT Pro/Sysadmin).

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not thinking about this for a data-center, just light soho usage.  As stated in the question, any reason routing/firewalling wouldn't work with vlans?  I thought most chips were ap-capable if the drivers being used supported it.  While a serial console is great, I think a monitor/keyboard has convenience advantages in a lot of situations.  Again, this is really as a cheap "good enough" sort of thing, not as a do-all low cost server.  It doesn't cover all scenarios, but I think for many there is a lot of potential value.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Your router/firewall is THE critical device in your network. If it dies, everything is inaccessible. Routing/firewalling would work with VLANs, but I would not trust the netbook's NIC (to be fair, the Soekris 5501 has terrifically bad NICs), nor would I trust it to perform well under high load or 24/7. In a SOHO environment you're much better off with a decent Linksys router flashed with DD-WRT. It'll cost you a lot less too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may be usable in a few niches, but the few netbooks I have actually had an opportunity to play with don't look like they are a reliable/well-built device.  I am not sure it would be wise to put anything of importance on one.

I guess if you keep good backups, and keep a spare around in case of a failure, and you can tolerate a short outage if there is a failure you could use one.

Comment: You're right, reliability is the big question.  Since these are meant as cheap consumer devices, they are likely to be a bit shoddy.  At least designers of embedded machines meant to be used as servers have motivation to work on reliability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 with [UNR](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download-netbook) on an Acer AspireOne.  It works really nicely.  The AA1 isn't the fastest machine, but it's not bad.  It's hard to see downside in what you're suggesting.

I guess there is the question of longevity, but at the price, it's hard not to think it's worth a try.  No RAID.  If it's in a dusty area, you going to have to pull it apart to clean the fan once in a while.

Comment: UNR wouldn't really be my first thought for a server ;)

Comment: If you were going to do a server with no GUI, no.  But I find it a  lot nicer to use on a netbook than the std Gnome UI

Comment: I'm personally only interested in the netbook's monitor/keyboard for the times that I can't use ssh anyway (for system-level upgrades or when the network is down for other reasons). But you're right, for graphical stuff, screen real-estate is precious and an optimized window manager is great.

Comment: BTW if you're thinking of soekris, take a look here http://www.pcengines.ch/.  we've used the ALIX & WRAP boards and have been very happy with them

Answer (score 0):

This actually sounds like a reasonably good idea to me, at least for small tasks.  The fact of having the display and keyboard built in as well as integrated battery backup I think seals the deal.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering a few netbooks (over wifi!) seems like a great idea... eh, I mean, hobby project anyway... let's get to it I say ^^

(Ahem, well yes, as you say, it got the major components; battery, flash drive and low noise and energy consumption. Wether the hardware itself is built to withstand 24/7 operation without ever entering sleep or being shut down is a different matter altogether)